# Select a single row of a list box in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python, listbox, pysimplegui

My question is simple, I'm a begginer in PySimpleGUI, and I want to know how do I change the color of text in a list box, but i want to change only some specific lines, so it's important that I can run all the list and select the lines.
Someone know how to do that, I'll be very thankfull.

Comment: You can change the text color for the entire list box with `text_color`. There is no way to change individual rows without going a level deeper (like to tk, but this would vary by OS, so it's not trivial.)

Comment: would a multiline with print work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tkinter code required to set options for items in listbox.

[image]

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme("DarkBlue")

items = ['USA', 'Mexico', 'Japan', 'Korea', 'UK', 'China', 'France']
asia_index = (2 ,3, 5)

layout = [
    [sg.Listbox(items, size=(10, 7), key='-LISTBOX-')],
]
window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
listbox = window['-LISTBOX-'].Widget
for index in asia_index:
    listbox.itemconfigure(index, bg='green', fg='white')    # set options for item in listbox
while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    print(event, values)

window.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the color of a text by adding **text_color**='COLOR' when creating it.

for exmaple:

```
Sg.Text("My text", key="sub_title", size=(15, 1), text_color='yellow')
```

And if you want to change the color of a button you'll need to use **button_color**=('FIRST_COLOR', 'SECOND_COLOR') just like below:

```
    Sg.Button("Update", key='update_button', size=(25, 1), button_color=('blue', 'purple'))
```

Enjoy.